# "No Source Video Found" error only with HLS streaming, Kaltura CE 6 and Wowza 4.1

Tags: ios, streaming, html5-video, wowza, kaltura

I'm having issues with HLS streaming and the HTML5 mwembed video player. I'm using mwembed v2.29.1.2, Kaltura CE 6.0, and Wowza Streaming Engine 4.1.2. Playing video through the Kaltura flash video player works fine, (streaming through Wowza with RTMP) but when trying to access the video on an iOS device, I get the message "Error: No source video was found."

I've tested the Wowza streaming directly and have not issues playing any of the videos directly: `http://wowza.medquestreviews.com/kaltura/_definst_/mp4:content/entry/data/4/268/0_uxutn4hk_0_v5nyr0u2_1/playlist.m3u8`

Here is a video with the issue: http://medquestreviews.com/step-3-high-yield/hematology/chapter-3-transfusion-reactions

I've looked through the Kaltura log files, apache_access, apache_errors, Kaltura_api_v3, etc. and the only error related to this that I can find is `"error-10"` in the apache log and `[thumbnailAction->execute] NOTICE: Error - no FileSync for entry` in the api log.

How can I go about finding the URL that Kaltura is using to look for the HLS stream? I've double checked the remote storage settings and everything is how it should be.

Accessing the m3u8 playlist/manifest itself works too: `http://kmc.medquestreviews.com/p/101/sp/10100/playManifest/entryId/0_uxutn4hk/format/applehttp/a.m3u8`

JS debug output from the HTML5 player is:

```
kWidget: Kaltura HTML5 Version: 2.29.1.2
11170242:1458kWidget: appendScriptUrls
load.php:1565getMarker> No <meta name="ResourceLoaderDynamicStyles"> found, inserting dynamically.
load.php:1565jQuery.fn.embedPlayer :: #kaltura-player
load.php:1565processEmbedPlayers:: playerSelector: #kaltura-player
load.php:1565EmbedPlayer:: addElement:: kaltura-player
load.php:1565processEmbedPlayers::runPlayerSwap::kaltura-player
load.php:1565EmbedPlayer::init:kaltura-player duration is: NaN, size: 355x200
load.php:1565EmbedPlayer::mediaElement:init:kaltura-player
load.php:1565processEmbedPlayers::swapEmbedPlayerElement: kaltura-player
load.php:1565processEmbedPlayers::trigger:: EmbedPlayerNewPlayer kaltura-player
11170242:1458kWidget: jsCallbackReady for kaltura-player
load.php:1565EmbedPlayer::addPlayerElement :trigger startPlayerBuildOut:kaltura-player
load.php:1565EmbedPlayer::checkPlayerSources: kaltura-player
load.php:1565KWidgetSupport::loadAndUpdatePlayerData
load.php:1565KWidgetSupport:: trigger Kaltura_CheckConfig
load.php:1565Error: function enableNativeControls should be implemented by embed player interface 
load.php:1565Warning: mediawiki.UtilitiesTime, trying to get npt time on NaN:NaN
load.php:1565Warning: mediawiki.UtilitiesTime, trying to get npt time on NaN:NaN
load.php:1565!!EmbedPlayer:updatePosterHTML:kaltura-player poster:http://kmc.medquestreviews.com/p/101/sp/10100/thumbnail/entry_id/0_mip1dmg3/version/100000/width/355/height/200
load.php:1565EmbedPlayer:updatePosterHTML:kaltura-player poster:http://kmc.medquestreviews.com/p/101/sp/10100/thumbnail/entry_id/0_mip1dmg3/version/100000/width/355/height/200
load.php:1565Error: EmbedPlayer, Must override 'addPlayScreenWithNativeOffScreen' with player inteface
load.php:1565KAnalytics :: doSendAnalyticsEvent > MEDIA_LOADED
load.php:1565KWidgetSupport:: trigger KalturaSupport_DoneWithUiConf
load.php:1565EmbedPlayer::setupSourcePlayer: kaltura-player sources: 0
load.php:1565EmbedPlayer::mediaElement::autoSelectSource
load.php:1565MediaElement::GetPlayableSources mimeFilter:undefined 0 sources playable out of 0
load.php:1565EmbedPlayer::showPlayerError
load.php:1565PlayerLayoutBuilder::displayAlert:: Error
load.php:1565PlayerLayoutBuilder:: displayMenuOverlay
load.php:1565EmbedPlayer::pause()
load.php:1565EmbedPlayer::pauseInterfaceUpdate
load.php:1565EmbedPlayer:: setupSourcePlayer > player ready ( but with errors ) 
load.php:1565LiveStream :: removeLiveStreamStatusMonitor
load.php:1565EmbedPlayer:: Trigger: widgetLoaded
load.php:1565KAnalytics :: doSendAnalyticsEvent > WIDGET_LOADED
```

---

I keep running into these lines in the kaltura_api_v3 log:

```
2015-04-21 16:56:59 [0.000160] [71.234.194.254] [1637142224] [PS2] [kFileSyncUtils::getReadyFileSyncForKey] NOTICE: kFileSyncUtils::getReadyFileSyncForKey - FileSync was found but doesn't exists locally
2015-04-21 16:56:59 [0.000116] [71.234.194.254] [1637142224] [PS2] [flvclipperAction->execute] NOTICE: Error - no FileSync for flavor [0_v5nyr0u2]
2015-04-21 16:56:59 [0.000139] [71.234.194.254] [1637142224] [PS2] [KExternalErrors::dieError] ERR: exiting on error 5 - required file was not found
```

Files are being stored locally as well as transferred via FTP to the Wowza server which is setup as a remote storage profile.

kaltura:

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxxx 268]$ ll *uxutn4hk*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 apache apache    150237 Oct 27 19:17 0_uxutn4hk_0_d6g74099_2.jpg
-rwxrwxrwx 1 apache apache    142816 Oct 27 19:31 0_uxutn4hk_0_jnagm88n_0.conv.log
-rwxrwxrwx 1 apache apache 139861815 Oct 27 19:31 0_uxutn4hk_0_jnagm88n_1.mp4
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache 326215877 Oct 27 19:17 0_uxutn4hk_0_v3a7ee0g_1.mp4
-rwxrwxrwx 1 apache apache     39239 Oct 27 19:20 0_uxutn4hk_0_v5nyr0u2_0.conv.log
-rwxrwxrwx 1 apache apache  35568566 Oct 27 19:20 0_uxutn4hk_0_v5nyr0u2_1.mp4
-rwxrwxrwx 1 apache apache     75212 Oct 27 19:24 0_uxutn4hk_0_ye4swbad_0.conv.log
-rwxrwxrwx 1 apache apache  86644533 Oct 27 19:24 0_uxutn4hk_0_ye4swbad_1.mp4
[ec2-user@ip-xxxx 268]$ pwd
/home/ec2-user/kaltura-app-dir/web/content/entry/data/4/268
```

wowza:

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxxx 268]$ ll *uxutn4hk*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 kaltura_ftp wowza 139861815 Oct 27 19:32 0_uxutn4hk_0_jnagm88n_1.mp4
-rwxrwxrwx 1 kaltura_ftp wowza 326215877 Oct 27 19:32 0_uxutn4hk_0_v3a7ee0g_1.mp4
-rwxrwxrwx 1 kaltura_ftp wowza  35568566 Oct 27 19:20 0_uxutn4hk_0_v5nyr0u2_1.mp4
-rwxrwxrwx 1 kaltura_ftp wowza  86644533 Oct 27 19:24 0_uxutn4hk_0_ye4swbad_1.mp4
[ec2-user@ip-xxxx 268]$ pwd
/media/video_content/content/entry/data/4/268
```

the Kaltura database file_sync table also has entries for the flavor asset:

```
id  partner_id  object_type object_id   version object_sub_type dc  original    created_at  updated_at  ready_at    sync_time   status  file_type   linked_id   link_count  file_root   file_path   file_size   custom_data
6350    101 4   0_v5nyr0u2  1   1   3   0   2014-10-27 15:20:20 2014-10-27 15:20:35 2014-10-27 15:20:35 NULL    2   3   NULL    NULL    /opt/kaltura/web/   /content/entry/data/4/268/0_uxutn4hk_0_v5nyr0u2_1.mp4   -1  NULL
6348    101 4   0_v5nyr0u2  1   1   0   1   2014-10-27 15:20:13 2014-10-27 15:20:35 2014-10-27 15:20:13 NULL    3   1   NULL    NULL    /opt/kaltura/web/   /content/entry/data/4/268/0_uxutn4hk_0_v5nyr0u2_1.mp4   35568566    NULL
6349    101 4   0_v5nyr0u2  0   2   0   1   2014-10-27 15:20:13 2014-10-27 15:20:13 2014-10-27 15:20:13 NULL    2   1   NULL    NULL    /opt/kaltura/web/   /content/entry/data/4/268/0_uxutn4hk_0_v5nyr0u2_0.conv.log  39239   NULL
```

The errors in the log also differ slightly depending on if I load the whole page with the embedded video or I try to load the dataUrl from the iframe player config JS.

logs from access whole page:

```
2015-04-21 17:14:13 [0.000241] [71.234.194.254] [753153844] [PS2] [kFileSyncUtils::getReadyLocalFilePathForKey] NOTICE: kFileSyncUtils::getReadyLocalFilePathForKey - key [object_type:[4], object_id:[0_v3a7ee0g], version:[1], object_sub_type[1], partner_id[101]], strict []
2015-04-21 17:14:13 [0.000158] [71.234.194.254] [753153844] [PS2] [kFileSyncUtils::getReadyFileSyncForKey] NOTICE: kFileSyncUtils::getReadyFileSyncForKey - key [object_type:[4], object_id:[0_v3a7ee0g], version:[1], object_sub_type[1], partner_id[101]], fetch_from_remote_if_no_local [], strict []
2015-04-21 17:14:13 [0.000932] [71.234.194.254] [753153844] [PS2] [KalturaStatement->execute] DEBUG: /* ip-10-239-172-244[753153844][propel2] */ SELECT file_sync.ID, file_sync.PARTNER_ID, file_sync.OBJECT_TYPE, file_sync.OBJECT_ID, file_sync.VERSION, file_sync.OBJECT_SUB_TYPE, file_sync.DC, file_sync.ORIGINAL, file_sync.CREATED_AT, file_sync.UPDATED_AT, file_sync.READY_AT, file_sync.SYNC_TIME, file_sync.STATUS, file_sync.FILE_TYPE, file_sync.LINKED_ID, file_sync.LINK_COUNT, file_sync.FILE_ROOT, file_sync.FILE_PATH, file_sync.FILE_SIZE FROM `file_sync` WHERE file_sync.OBJECT_ID='0_v3a7ee0g' AND file_sync.OBJECT_TYPE='4' AND file_sync.OBJECT_SUB_TYPE='1' AND file_sync.VERSION='1' AND file_sync.DC='0' AND (file_sync.STATUS='2' AND file_sync.STATUS NOT IN ('3','4')) ORDER BY file_sync.DC ASC
2015-04-21 17:14:13 [0.000438] [71.234.194.254] [753153844] [PS2] [KalturaStatement->execute] DEBUG: Sql took - 0.00026082992553711 seconds
2015-04-21 17:14:13 [0.000187] [71.234.194.254] [753153844] [PS2] [kFileSyncUtils::getReadyFileSyncForKey] NOTICE: kFileSyncUtils::getReadyFileSyncForKey - FileSync was not found
2015-04-21 17:14:13 [0.000749] [71.234.194.254] [753153844] [PS2] [kCoreException->__construct] ERR: Code: [1] Message: [no ready filesync on current DC]
2015-04-21 17:14:13 [0.000670] [71.234.194.254] [753153844] [PS2] [KalturaStatement->execute] DEBUG: /* ip-10-239-172-244[753153844][propel2] */ SELECT flavor_asset.ID, flavor_asset.INT_ID, flavor_asset.PARTNER_ID, flavor_asset.TAGS, flavor_asset.CREATED_AT, flavor_asset.UPDATED_AT, flavor_asset.DELETED_AT, flavor_asset.ENTRY_ID, flavor_asset.FLAVOR_PARAMS_ID, flavor_asset.STATUS, flavor_asset.VERSION, flavor_asset.DESCRIPTION, flavor_asset.WIDTH, flavor_asset.HEIGHT, flavor_asset.BITRATE, flavor_asset.FRAME_RATE, flavor_asset.SIZE, flavor_asset.IS_ORIGINAL, flavor_asset.FILE_EXT, flavor_asset.CONTAINER_FORMAT, flavor_asset.VIDEO_CODEC_ID, flavor_asset.TYPE, flavor_asset.CUSTOM_DATA FROM `flavor_asset` WHERE flavor_asset.ENTRY_ID='0_uxutn4hk' AND flavor_asset.IS_ORIGINAL='1' AND flavor_asset.STATUS<>'3' LIMIT 1
2015-04-21 17:14:13 [0.000400] [71.234.194.254] [753153844] [PS2] [KalturaStatement->execute] DEBUG: Sql took - 0.00022983551025391 seconds
2015-04-21 17:14:13 [0.000927] [71.234.194.254] [753153844] [PS2] [KalturaStatement->execute] DEBUG: /* ip-10-239-172-244[753153844][propel2] */ SELECT file_sync.ID, file_sync.PARTNER_ID, file_sync.OBJECT_TYPE, file_sync.OBJECT_ID, file_sync.VERSION, file_sync.OBJECT_SUB_TYPE, file_sync.DC, file_sync.ORIGINAL, file_sync.CREATED_AT, file_sync.UPDATED_AT, file_sync.READY_AT, file_sync.SYNC_TIME, file_sync.STATUS, file_sync.FILE_TYPE, file_sync.LINKED_ID, file_sync.LINK_COUNT, file_sync.FILE_ROOT, file_sync.FILE_PATH, file_sync.FILE_SIZE FROM `file_sync` WHERE file_sync.OBJECT_ID='0_v3a7ee0g' AND file_sync.OBJECT_TYPE='4' AND file_sync.OBJECT_SUB_TYPE='1' AND file_sync.VERSION='1' AND file_sync.ORIGINAL='1' AND file_sync.STATUS NOT IN ('3','4')
2015-04-21 17:14:13 [0.000468] [71.234.194.254] [753153844] [PS2] [KalturaStatement->execute] DEBUG: Sql took - 0.00028085708618164 seconds
2015-04-21 17:14:13 [0.000202] [71.234.194.254] [753153844] [PS2] [thumbnailAction->execute] NOTICE: Error - no FileSync for entry [0_uxutn4hk]
2015-04-21 17:14:13 [0.000207] [71.234.194.254] [753153844] [PS2] [KExternalErrors::dieError] ERR: exiting on error 10 - missing thumbnail fileSync for entry
```

accessing dataUrl directly: `http://kmc.medquestreviews.com/p/101/sp/10100/flvclipper/entry_id/0_uxutn4hk/version/0`

```
2015-04-21 17:17:26 [0.000106] [71.234.194.254] [1347402480] [PS2] [kFileSyncUtils::getReadyFileSyncForKey] NOTICE: kFileSyncUtils::getReadyFileSyncForKey - key [object_type:[4], object_id:[0_v5nyr0u2], version:[1], object_sub_type[1], partner_id[101]], fetch_from_remote_if_no_local [1], strict []
2015-04-21 17:17:26 [0.000733] [71.234.194.254] [1347402480] [PS2] [KalturaStatement->execute] DEBUG: /* ip-10-239-172-244[1347402480][propel] */ SELECT file_sync.ID, file_sync.PARTNER_ID, file_sync.OBJECT_TYPE, file_sync.OBJECT_ID, file_sync.VERSION, file_sync.OBJECT_SUB_TYPE, file_sync.DC, file_sync.ORIGINAL, file_sync.CREATED_AT, file_sync.UPDATED_AT, file_sync.READY_AT, file_sync.SYNC_TIME, file_sync.STATUS, file_sync.FILE_TYPE, file_sync.LINKED_ID, file_sync.LINK_COUNT, file_sync.FILE_ROOT, file_sync.FILE_PATH, file_sync.FILE_SIZE FROM `file_sync` WHERE file_sync.OBJECT_ID='0_v5nyr0u2' AND file_sync.OBJECT_TYPE='4' AND file_sync.OBJECT_SUB_TYPE='1' AND file_sync.VERSION='1' AND (file_sync.STATUS='2' AND file_sync.STATUS NOT IN ('3','4')) ORDER BY file_sync.DC ASC
2015-04-21 17:17:26 [0.000419] [71.234.194.254] [1347402480] [PS2] [KalturaStatement->execute] DEBUG: Sql took - 0.00025010108947754 seconds
2015-04-21 17:17:26 [0.000241] [71.234.194.254] [1347402480] [PS2] [kFileSyncUtils::getReadyFileSyncForKey] NOTICE: kFileSyncUtils::getReadyFileSyncForKey - FileSync was found but doesn't exists locally
2015-04-21 17:17:26 [0.000169] [71.234.194.254] [1347402480] [PS2] [flvclipperAction->execute] NOTICE: Error - no FileSync for flavor [0_v5nyr0u2]
2015-04-21 17:17:26 [0.000212] [71.234.194.254] [1347402480] [PS2] [KExternalErrors::dieError] ERR: exiting on error 5 - required file was not found
```

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: It tries to access `http://kmc.medquestreviews.com/p/101/sp/10100/thumbnail/entry_id/0_uxutn4hk/version/100000/width/100/vid_slices/100` which results in `X-Kaltura-App: exiting on error 10 - missing thumbnail fileSync for entry`. It actually dies on that error for some reason.

Comment: thanks for taking a look at this @aergistal. I was about to edit the post with some more information... It appears there are filesync entries in the database for these items, and the files are stored on both locally and on the remote wowza server. These errors seemed to start when I added and then removed an additional remote storage profile, but did not edit the one for wowza.

Comment: Kaltura did a lot of HLS improvements in the CE10X version. Did you consider upgrading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is resolved.
We fixed this by using a newer version of the Kaltura CE and using the native HLS integration it has in it.
We also upgraded the player and the HLS plugin.